# Why I can't get wrong value for yearly_revenue

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel

```
public function revenue(){
      $today = Carbon::today();
      $date = Carbon::createFromDate(2019, 3, 1);
      $daily_revenue = $this->getRevenue($today->format('Y-m-d 00:00:00'), $today->format('Y-m-d 23:59:59'));
      $monthly_revenue = $this->getRevenue(Carbon::today()->startOfMonth(), Carbon::today()->endOfMonth());
      $yearly_revenue = $this->getRevenue(Carbon::createFromDate()->startOfYear(), Carbon::createFromDate()->EndOfYear());
      dd($yearly_revenue);
      return view('layouts/home', ['']);
    }

    private function getRevenue($date_from, $date_to) {
      $revenue = Sales::whereBetween('created_at', [$date_from, $date_to])
        ->sum('grand_price');

      return $revenue;
    }
```

I have tested my 
**daily_revenue and monthly_revenue is fine**
 but **yearly_revenue** I don't know how to do it. Please Help.

Comment: You need to clarify what you mean.

Comment: sorry... i bad on my clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `createFromDate` you can use `now` this will give you the current year:

```
$yearly_revenue = $this->getRevenue(Carbon::now()->startOfYear(), Carbon::now()->endOfYear());
```

Comment: @RaymondNijland look at his code the same line that I have changed and you will see why I suggested this way.

Comment: never mind mine comment now i see why you suggested it.

Comment: @RaymondNijland sorry for make u confuse... i just started so many things don't know... and im not good on english =(